# Does Laravel Mix support ES8?

Tags: laravel, async-await, laravel-mix, ecmascript-2017

I'm compiling my javascript files with Laravel mix, and as I am not very knowledgeable yet on Babel and package.json, I want to ask if Laravel Mix supports ES8, especially async/await?

If I try it, I can't tell if Mix is transpiling async/await to ES5 or if async/await is simply supported by my browser, which is the latest version. I still want it to be transpiled to ES2015 so the application will still works on browsers that only support ES5.

Comment: Laravel Mix uses babel under the hood, if the correct plugins are added to babel the async/await syntax is supported. I'm currently investigating how to do this, I'll let you know.

Comment: @Cobolt great, any help would be appreciated. Excited to know how your investigation goes, I'm stumped as I don't know where to start looking, I've Googled a lot but to no avail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**async / await with Laravel Mix:**

If you use Laravel Mix out of the Box and use async and await you get the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

But Laravel Mix uses Babel to support ES2015. We can customise the compilation if we need to.

To get async / await working, add the file `.babelrc` to your root directory with this content:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

And install the needed npm packages:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-3 babel-plugin-transform-runtime --save-dev
```

The important thing (which caused the error) is the transform-runtime plugin. It is not shipped with Laravel Mix, but you need it in order to get the async / await feature working.

**ES8:**

As you have seen above, you can use different preset stages in Babel. With them you can use features that are included in ES8 or later. For example *stage-3* brings the async / await feature.

They have an [overview of the stages](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-stage-x-experimental-presets-) on their website.

Comment: It's recommended that you use `babel-preset-env`. It contains both es2015 & stage-3. Then you just need `["env"]`